# run angular projects on vagrant VM

Tags: angular, nginx, vagrant

I need to use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to run an Angular project so we can do testing in specific OS environments.

I have managed to set Vagrant up and started an Ubuntu VM. I can SSH into the VM and access my files in the host machine through it as well, which seems like an important step.

I tried accessing the host directory from the VM and running the command `ng serve` but it simply loads up to 10% and then stops without any error message.
After some research I think I have to do this through port forwarding which I don't have much (or any) experience with.

We usually use nginx to serve and test the project, how can I do this but make it run in the Ubuntu virtual environment? How can I configure my Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend to use a shared directory. I believe you have stored your project in any Git. Clone the project on your VM and serve it from a local directory.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but Vagrant is supposed to be set up so that you can run projects in the same directory as the Vagrantfile from the VM.

I would still like to try it though, how can I clone a project to a VM with no GUI?

Comment: I get the following error:
`Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: You didn't just type 'git clone', did you? Please check the link I provided for further details on the command. Scroll down for examples.

Comment: No of course i didn't just write 'git clone', why would I have gotten an error message about reading the repository?
Also cloning the enitre project into a VM everytime we want to test a new environment would be very counterproductive, I am looking for a solution where I can simply set up the virtual machine and serve it through Vagrant, if anyone has experience with Vagrant they should be able to tell me how to do that.